# Extract value from a specific div with same class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on getting specific div data, and trying [jQuery.](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>load demo</title>
 <style>
 body {
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: Arial;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Projects:</b>
<ol id="funds"></ol>

<script>
$( "#funds" ).load( "https://www.app.greaterchange.co.uk/give#47  graphic-number" ); //want to get 64
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can achieve this with javascript? Please help me.

Comment: There are no div in your html structure. And explain exactly what you want.

Comment: Its getting HTML page from that [URL](https://www.app.greaterchange.co.uk/give#47), did you study jQuery [link](https://api.jquery.com/load/). I am trying this to use

Comment: Ah, ok. I apologize.

Comment: have you a Cors error?

Comment: so i dont think you could load an url like this: 1) you have  a security protocol problem with https, 2) you'll have a cors problem, the only way i see, is to load the file with the server and send result to client.....

Answer (score 1):

By reading the js script inside the page web about `https://www.app.greaterchange.co.uk/give#47`, you could see it loads the page by sending the url `https://www.app.greaterchange.co.uk/give/ajax/47` (respons to a click on picture) . i suggest you to use this url if you want to trap some values.

so you could dowload the url and search easily the datas you need..but this thing could only be done with the server and not client.

I suggest you to post a request GET or POST to the server and the server will return the values wanted.

If your server is node.js you could use [cherio](http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-javascript-and-node-js/) to download the content of the page.

If your server is C#, you could use [DownloadString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring?view=netframework-4.8)

and dont forget to authorize the protocol tls11 or tls12...(https)

For precision you could keep .load function, but you modify the call by removing https: for example:

```
.load( "/www.app.greaterchange.co.uk/give#47  graphic-number" );
```

the  server will receive a GET request with the url in its arguments. The url will be change to `give/ajax/47`.